# In node.js, json object should be converted to string type?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

I'm the beginner of node.js and React. While I am watching some videos about node.js and React, I saw when we fetch data to node.js(req), it use json.stringify(). On the other hand, when we fetch data to React(res), it use json.parse().

I think in React, json is existed in object, in node.js, json is existed in string. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, JSON is an object irrespective of where it is used, (it is object even for other programming languages like Java, C#, Python, etc)

I believe you are confused with code. when we are sending request body or receiving response body which is in transit HTTP doesn't understand the object, so when we send the request we make it string (which json.stringify part or Serialise) and when we receive it in order to again make it JSON we do json.parse (deserialize).